# Async Apex & Fault Tolerance

Tags: apex, callout, asynchronous, queue

Trying to see if I can make Async Apex jobs fault tolerant; meaning if they fail can I implement some sort of retry logic?

What would this retry mechanism look like and is there any documentation or any examples of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview**

In salesforce you can implement or execute a variety of asynchronous [APEX jobs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm). E.g. "Future", "SharingRecalculation", "ScheduledApex" or "BatchApex".

The retry mechanism will look different from case to case. One of the most easiest solutions is a batch job.

**Solution outline for a batch job**

Create a custom object called "log". In this object you can store information about your failed jobs. It is useful to collect information about the job, the error message and the affected records.

**How to resolve issues**

After the error is logged in your "log" object you can exclude the records associated with unresolved issues from your batch job. And send a request to one of your users to resolve the issue for you. The user should read the error message and mark the issue as resolved.